Doubt regarding Implicit Function Theorem in Spivak
On page 42 of Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak, he presents the following proof of the Implicit function theorem:
Proof: Define $F:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ by $F(x,y) = \bigl(x,f(x,y)\bigr)$.
Notice that $DF(x,y) = \bigl(1,Df(x,y)\bigr)$. In particular, we have $\det\bigl(DF(a,b)\bigr) = \det\bigl(Df(a,b)\bigr) \neq 0$.
Applying the inverse function theorem on $F$, we get that there exist open sets $V,W$, which contain $(a,b)$, $F(a,b) = (a,0)$, respectively.
For such sets $V,W$, it holds that $F:V\to W$ has a differentiable inverse $F^{-1}:W\to V$. Since $F$ is the identity on $x$, then so is $F^{-1}$. In other words, $F^{-1}$ has the form $F^{-1}(x,y) = \bigl(x,k(x,y)\bigr)$ for some differentiable function $k$.
Now, define $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ to be the function given by the rule $(x,y)\mapsto y$. This way, we get that $\pi\circ F=f$.
Furthermore, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(f\circ F^{-1})(x,y) 
&= f\bigl(x,k(x,y)\bigr) \\
&= \bigl((\pi\circ F)\circ F^{-1}\bigr)(x,y) \tag{1} \\
&= \bigl(\pi\circ (F\circ F^{-1})\bigr)(x,y) \tag{2} \\
&= (\pi \circ I)(x,y)\\
&= y.
\end{align}
$$
And the proof continues...
My only question so far is: How did Spivak go from $(1)$ to $(2)$? What allowed him to "commute" the composition of functions?

function composition is associative

@Andrew Thanks! I was so confused I didn't even noticed that the property I was looking for was associativity and not commutativity
